# Enable disable features disappeared from acumatica

Tags: acumatica

In versions 4 of Acumatica it was possible to turn on/off some features of Acumatica in trial mode ( for two users only ). But for now I can't find this window. Is it removed from Acumatica or renamed?
In the past after installation of Acumatica, I was able to see it at following path: Configuration -> Common Settings -> Licensing -> Enable/Disable Features
but for now I just see following picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yuri, I believe you attached screenshot of a website created with Acumatica Framework Configuration Wizard. We do not ship **Enable/Disable Features** screen anymore as part of Acumatica Framework anymore:

[image]

It's only possible to access **Enable/Disable Features** screen on Acumatica ERP websites (those deployed with Acumatica ERP Configuration Wizard):

[image]

Comment: In such case, how can I gain access to other screens and modules?

Comment: Sorry @RuslanDev, I didn't notice initially difference between Acumatica Framework Configuration Wizard and Acumatica ERP Configuration Wizard

Comment: That's okay, Yuriy. Hope everything is clear now and you can move forward with your project.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find this window in :
Configuration -> Common Settings -> Licensing -> Enable/Disable Features

Comment: Thanks samol518, but at that path I just see error message. See modified question with screenshot